# Research on number of exam attempts vs. learning outcome

Tags: exams, reference-request, learning

Is there research on how allowing retakes or multiple attempts affects the learning outcome of students?

For instance, if one allows students 3 attempts to take the exam rather than 1, with tests taken from the same randomized pool, do they end up knowing the course material better?

Motivation for the question: the Italian system allows for many retakes; it would be interesting to quantify what their effect is.

Comment: Probably impossible to do the research. How do you know the outcome without a "test"? And a very careful design would be needed to avoid ethical issues unless the measurement in the research is divorced from grading. But it has generally been known that "practice makes perfect." Moreover, does test "performance" correlate well with "learning"? They are not the same, necessarily. One could ask, of course, whether the later attempts score higher than the earlier ones without too many issues.

Comment: But even the last has issues of interpretation if students know that multiple tries are possible. How hard to they work for the first sitting? So, there are still issues.

Comment: @Buffy To answer your first question: you can do another (one-shot, non-graded) test to check the mastery of the material.

Comment: *How hard to they work for the first sitting?* Why does it matter?

Comment: Because students, being students, might not prepare as well for the first sitting if they know they can fill in gaps having seen that version. So, the grades on the first try might be artificially low.

Comment: Yet another issue is how do you justify that "extra" non graded test? Some would consider it abuse unless you "pay" them somehow and paying them will also probably skew the results (in unknown ways). Tough problem.

Comment: @Buffy That first test preparation issue, in my mind, is part of the effect you want to measure. How would academia work with more exams than the Western standard? How would the student modify their study process? That's part of the research question.

Comment: "Abuse" for the extra test seems a strong word. And if paying participants is considered unacceptable because it skews the results of a test, then I imagine that a large body of existing literature would be invalidated.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/140740/discussion-between-federico-poloni-and-buffy).

Comment: I know it's late in Pisa, but I've added thoughts in that chatroom.

Comment: I don't know if there is any research on this topic. Here are some of my thoughts from my observations.  1. You will probably find the average grade increases after students retaking the exam; however, this is a very biased conclusion as they only accept the score if they get a better score after retaking.

Comment: 2. Allowing students to retake the exam without consequence is a waste of time. Some students will have a ton of delayed exams. They miss lectures because they want to prepare to retake past exams. Or they decide to prepare for the skipped exams just a few weeks before taking them.  They may get a better score, but it only simply reflects the fact that they "learn" the material instead of understanding the material. It is not hard to tell this. As a professor, you can easily know if your students truly understand something or they just memorize things.

Comment: @buffy and there's a whole school of thought (Competency-Based Education) where they are perfectly happy with that. The point is on whether students can pass, not on how hard they study. With that mindset, students deciding not to study the first time just to see if they already know the material and then only studying if they fail is logical and reasonable.